# Select In Stock Items

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a script to perform a click action to only select in-stock items. But I'm having a hard time selecting the content "Disponible"

HTML below:

```
<div class="top namePartPriceContainer">

                    <span id="InventoryStatus_OnlineStatus_691003" class="text inventoryStatus inv-status-3" itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/InStock" content="Disponible">In Stock
                    </span>


    <div id="InventoryStatus_ShowLink_Section_691003" class="left available" style="display:none;">
        <span class="text Select attributes to see availability">Select attributes to see availability
        </span>
    </div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var products = document.getElementById("dijit__WidgetBase_0");
var items = products.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
 if(items[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText === "In Stock"){
     document.getElementById("productPageAdd2Cart").click();
 }
}
```

Comment: It clicks on the first item but it only click on the first item out a list of 11 items. I want the logic to not click on "out of stock" items. Im thinking my if statement is incorrect.

Comment: You need to share more of your HTML. The Javascript queries the li tags but these are not in your HTML.

Comment: Your for loop is running through list items. Is it possible to include the markup for this as part of your question? It would help to understand better where your problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getAttribute(); looks like the solution for you.

```
var content = document.getElementById('id').getAttribute('content');
```

and then:

```
if(content == 'Disponible') {
    document.getElementById("productPageAdd2Cart").click();
}
```